# android error parsing package

Tags: android, parsing, package

I have the following problem:
My application download the latest version APK and save the APK file in the / data / data / package name / upgrade.
Until here everything works perfectly.
Then the application executes the following code to start the installation:

```
String file = "/data/data/" + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/upgrade/myapp.apk";

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");

startActivity(intent);
```

After received an error: "Error parsing package".
And the installation does not start.
If I download the same file from the browser work fine.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am having the same issue on Android 4.3